# Add iphone sdk 6.1 on xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

how to install iphone sdk 6.1 on xcode 4.3 ? 
I want to add new latest sdk to the current xcode. I'm using VMWARE MAC OSX Lion 10.7.1 and I have unlocked iphone device which have ios 6.1 version. What I want to do is to build a iphone app with xcode for my iphone

Comment: You must have to update your xCode to newer version for latest SDK to support.

Comment: You have to download latest xcode which has the sdk supporting iOS 6.1

Comment: Always use the latest Xcode version

Comment: The latest SDK isnt 6.1 it is 7. You will need to download xCode 5 in order to have SDK 7. If you want to work on an older version (6.1) then you will need to download the version of xCode that matches that SDK (4.5 I think)

Comment: but MAC won't let me install latest xcode, because my mac version is 10.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Select Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads. You should be able to see all the available sdks to download.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor can you please give me an answer if you know ?

Answer (score 0):

To use iOS 6.1 & even 7.0, update the latest Xcode from Mac App Store.

Comment: but MAC won't let me install latest xcode, because my mac version is 10.7.1

Comment: Then upgrade your Mac OS X as well. Developers should use the latest tool to deliver up-to-standard work.